# ogr2ogr reprojection issues

Tags: coordinate-system, ogr2ogr

I have a geodatabase that I would like to convert to shapefile with epsg:4326 projection. For this I use ogr2ogr.

However when I reproject, the results are off[image]. They seem to have shifted?

Any idea why?

The commands I'm using:

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/python35/bin/ogr2ogr -f 'ESRI Shapefile' /volumes/data/Y2018M08D13_RH_Process_Basisregistratie_Gewaspercelen_V01/process2_V07/BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.shp /volumes/data/Y2018M08D13_RH_Process_Basisregistratie_Gewaspercelen_V01/process_V07/BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.gdb
```

and then convert to epsg 4326 (I used to do everything in one step but split for debugging purposes)

```
/opt/anaconda3/envs/python35/bin/ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 /volumes/data/Y2018M08D13_RH_Process_Basisregistratie_Gewaspercelen_V01/output_V07/BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.shp /volumes/data/Y2018M08D13_RH_Process_Basisregistratie_Gewaspercelen_V01/process2_V07/BRP_Gewaspercelen_2009.shp
```

Geodatabase: http://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/brpgewaspercelen/extract/2009-definitief/brpgewaspercelen.zip

The file geodatabase has this metadata crs:

```
+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,-0.398957,0.343988,-1.87740,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs
```

Comment: What projection is your basemap in?

Comment: web mercator, OTF reprojection

Comment: My guess is that the crs of the geodatabase is different than what it should be. Might need to overwrite input crs

Comment: yes! adding s_src EPSG:28992 did the job. Too bad the official shapefiles of the Netherlands are in the wrong projection :s

Comment: Did you try to make a conversion directly from gdb without going through shapefiles or by using for example GeoPackage as an interim format?

Comment: I tried `ogr2ogr -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f 'ESRI Shapefile' outfile.shp infile.gdb`

Comment: and this worked:  `ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f 'ESRI Shapefile' outfile.shp infile.gdb`

Comment: You should add this as an answer and close it. I can see myself getting tripped up on this as well.

Comment: @AndreJ can you turn your comment into an answer, can accept as answered then,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The projection of the shapefiles is not wrong, it just lacks the datum shift (as ESRI shapefiles do per definition, while ogr2ogr needs it). So you have to add the EPSG code for the source and target CRS to do it right.

From your comment, this command line works:

```
 ogr2ogr -s_srs EPSG:28992 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -f 'ESRI Shapefile' outfile.shp infile.gdb
```